# Editing images in Rich Text Field

Tags: craft-features

I used to be able to resize and select align attributes for images in Rich Text and now that feature is completely gone since my last update. Do I need to change settings or has that feature actually been removed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, image resizing and alignment is still available in Redactor II
<sub>(at least it is by now, might have been different a year ago)</sub>

It seems that in Reactor II both of those have to be enabled explicitly in the config. [See Redactor docs](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/images/#setting-imageResizable)

In Craft CMS you can modify the config in `craft/config/redactor`. Or create a new file and select it in the Control Panel. [More details](https://craftcms.com/docs/rich-text-fields#redactor-configs)

My `Standard.json` looks something like this:

```
{
    "buttons": [...],
    "plugins": [...],
    "imageResizable": true,
    "imagePosition": true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Alot of features were removed from Redactor II which Craft 2.5 upgraded to. Good thing is, you can revert back to using Redactor I, by installing [this plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorI) from Pixel & Tonic.